# Border is not come back, removed hover from element in EDGE

Tags: html, css

I want the border to normal position  after remove hover from  an element,this is working fine in chrome,Firefox,BUT NOT WORKING IN EDGE

```
  <span class="cta-content">
       <span class="cta-text">demo</span>
       <span class="icon">i</span>
   </span>
```

```css
.cta-content{
            background: linear-gradient(0deg, blue, blue) bottom left no-repeat;
            background-color: none !important;
            background-size: 0px 1px;
            transition: 0.5s background-size;
            text-decoration: none;
            display: inline !important;
        }
        .cta-content:hover{
            background-size: 100% 1px;
            color:red;
        }
```

```html
  <span class="cta-content">
           <span class="cta-text">demo</span>
           <span class="icon">i</span>
       </span>
```

Comment: What version of Edge do you use? Works great for me on Edge v.42.

Comment: i am using V.41

Comment: Works for me as well on Edge v42

Comment: Works fine in v.41 here...

Answer (score 0):

Always add the HTML rendering engine.

```css
.cta-content {
  background: linear-gradient(0deg, blue, blue) bottom left no-repeat;
  background-color: none !important;
  background-size: 0px 1px;
  -webkit-transition: 0.5s background-size;
  -moz-transition: 0.5s background-size;
  -o-transition: 0.5s background-size;
  transition: 0.5s background-size;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline !important;
}

.cta-content:hover {
  background-size: 100% 1px;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<span class="cta-content">
       <span class="cta-text">demo</span>
<span class="icon">i</span>
</span>
```